# Android, PowerMock: Test class in folder androidTest: javassist.NotFoundException:

Tags: powermock

I want to test static method on my Android app.

My build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.21"
    androidTestCompile "org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6"
    androidTestCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.6'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.6'
}
```

My PowerMock test for Android app:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StringUtil.class)
public class StringUtilInstrumentedTest {
    private Context context;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();
    }

    @Test
    public void decliningAge() {
        mockStatic(StringUtil.class);

        // use Mockito to set up your expectation
        String expected = "first";
        when(StringUtil.calcAge(context, 1)).thenReturn(expected);
        assertThat(StringUtil.calcAge(context, 1), is(expected));     
    }
}
```

But when I try to start test, throw exception:

```
I/TestRunner(32154): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.StringUtilInstrumentedTest
I/TestRunner(32154):    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
I/TestRunner(32154): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name com.mycompany.StringUtilInstrumentedTest. Reason: com.mycompany.StringUtilInstrumentedTest
org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadMockClass(MockClassLoader.java
I/TestRunner(32154): Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: com.mycompany.StringUtilInstrumentedTest
I/TestRunner(32154):    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:452)
```

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `StringUtilInstrumentedTest` resides in `src/test/java` then PowerMock could be used. But if it is in `src/androidTest/java` then it won't work.

PowerMock doesn't work with Android Instrumentation tests. Refer this:  https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/594

> Sorry for the late response. PowerMock won't work on Android if you run it on a device since PowerMock is using JVM byte code manipulation. It will work if you run it on a JVM though.

Comment: Yes, I start StringUtilInstrumentedTest from folder "src/androidTest/java".